# Sound waves creating bubbles in water

Tags: visible-light, waves, acoustics, water, bubbles

Sorry for the title, couldn't find a better one.

A few years ago I read on a scientific magazine about a discovery, but I can't remember the name nor find anymore information on it. Basically they discovered that by emitting certain sound waves in the direction of a water container created in water itself microscopic short-living bubbles at very high temperatures (maybe in the order of millions of degrees?)

I've lost the magazine, and as I wrote I tried to find information for a long time, but with no luck. Does anybody has a clue about what I'm talking about?

Comment: Sonoluminescese creates bubbles, high temperature,  light and other radiation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you may be referring to Sonoluminescence.

One of the most commonly held theories about the causes of occurrence of sonoluminescence is the idea that when a bubble collapses, the air inside gets pressurized. Increasing the pressure on a gas increases the temperature of the gas. In cases where the temperature inside the tiny bubbles becomes pretty high the gas begins to glow.

Another theory on sonoluminescence is that the collapsing bubble leads energy to prolong the life of the otherwise quickly annihilating photons that are spontaneously generated in a vacuum. Sonoluminescence could also be the product of the way photons can pop into and out of existence; the sudden collapse of the bubble making the photons noticeable to those in the macro world

Originally Posted: http://thetechjournal.com/science/sonoluminescence-light-is-created-by-sound-wave.xhtml#ixzz3w68qf0XS 
Follow us: @TheTechJournal on Twitter